# How to use SUM and SUBSTRACT by different WHERE statements?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, ms-access

I am trying to sum `dbo.OperacijosPard_SK.SumaBePVM` by
`dbo_OperacijuTIpai_SK.OperacijuTipaiID = 50` and substract by `dbo_OperacijuTIpai_SK.OperacijuTipaiID = 61`

Is there an easier way than creating 2 queries with SUM of `_Id = 50`, and `_Id = 61` and then joining?

```
SELECT dbo_Partneriai_SK.Pavad, 
       Sum(dbo_OperacijosPard_SK.SumaBePVM) AS SumOfSumaBePVM
FROM (dbo_OperacijosPard_SK 
INNER JOIN dbo_Partneriai_SK 
ON dbo_OperacijosPard_SK.PartneriaiId = dbo_Partneriai_SK.PartneriaiId) 
INNER JOIN dbo_OperacijuTipai_SK 
ON dbo_OperacijosPard_SK.OperacijuTipaiId=dbo_OperacijuTipai_SK.OperacijuTipaiId
WHERE (((dbo_OperacijosPard_SK.Data)>#1/1/2021#) 
AND ((dbo_OperacijuTipai_SK.OperacijuTipaiId)=50 
Or (dbo_OperacijuTipai_SK.OperacijuTipaiId)=61))
GROUP BY dbo_Partneriai_SK.Pavad
ORDER BY Sum(dbo_OperacijosPard_SK.SumaBePVM) DESC;
```

Comment: Where are you subtracting anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   dbo_Partneriai_SK.Pavad
   , Sum(case when OperacijuTipaiId=50 then dbo_OperacijosPard_SK.SumaBePVM else 0 end) 
   - Sum(case when OperacijuTipaiId=61 then dbo_OperacijosPard_SK.SumaBePVM else 0 end) AS SumOfSumaBePVM
FROM (dbo_OperacijosPard_SK 
INNER JOIN dbo_Partneriai_SK ON dbo_OperacijosPard_SK.PartneriaiId = dbo_Partneriai_SK.PartneriaiId) 
INNER JOIN dbo_OperacijuTipai_SK ON dbo_OperacijosPard_SK.OperacijuTipaiId = dbo_OperacijuTipai_SK.OperacijuTipaiId
WHERE (((dbo_OperacijosPard_SK.Data)>#1/1/2021#) AND ((dbo_OperacijuTipai_SK.OperacijuTipaiId)=50 Or (dbo_OperacijuTipai_SK.OperacijuTipaiId)=61))
GROUP BY dbo_Partneriai_SK.Pavad
ORDER BY Sum(dbo_OperacijosPard_SK.SumaBePVM) DESC;
```

Comment: I execute this SQL through Pandas and I get Pavad column with values in all rows, but in Sum I only get value in one of the rows, while all others are NaNs.

Comment: @Aduomas ok , see updated answer , added `else` in the sum calculation

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but I'm still struggling to use even basic SQL syntax like this on my own.